# Use Base Tree from XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

Is there a way to only use the base decision tree that is used in the XGBoost algorithm?

I know that Sklearn's GBT just uses a Sklearn Decision Tree as their base but XGBoost builds trees differently (e.g. regularization of the leaf weights).

I looked at the code for XGBoost but I wasn't able to figure out how they built their base tree.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for you:

1. Build only 1 tree (meaning use only 1 iteration), that means that when you train use `num_boost_round=1`
2. When you predict use `ntree_limit=1`

Either one will solve your problem. You either train only 1 tree or you predict using only 1 tree.

Comment: Would num_boost_round = 1 be the 'base' tree? Wouldn't it be the initialization of gradient boosting (a weak estimator) and then one iteration learning from that error using the base tree?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use their implementation of a decision tree?

Comment: maybe you mean this link https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/src/tree/tree_model.cc ?